# App crashes when hitting rewind button multiples times

Tags: iphone

Application crashes and message is program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when hitting purposely on rewind button multiple times just to test application on iPhone device.

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
[timer invalidate];
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[viewController release];
[self playpauseAction:_playButton];
}

-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

    if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }
    } 
    }

 -(void)pauseTimer{
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];

previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];

[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
  }

-(void)resumeTimer{
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];

[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
}


 -(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
 {
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
 }

 -(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
 }
```

i don't know why it is crashing may be because of the resume timer or may be because of the view controller i released.

Comment: what you want to do exactly??

Comment: Could you post code for pauseTimer and resumeTimer methods? I see you have a [timer invalidate] message, but you also use methods to operate the timer

Comment: i just edited my post please check

Answer (score 1):

Why do you alloc and init your MainViewController inside of your rewind function? that seems odd to me, normally you only need to initialize your viewcontroller once, not every time a method is called. And similarly, you release it at the end of the method, which is also strange. Generally errors that take multiple clicks to be caused are caused by memory management problems. I'm guessing that something is being removed from memory (possibly your view controller) and then you are trying to access it, giving you a bad access error.

To debug this, use NSZombies, which allows you to see what was removed from memory. A tutorial of how to use it can be found [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/)

Comment: reason i am initing mainviewcontroller inside rewind function because when rewind or play is pressed it plays audio file and at the same time loads multiple view controllers one after the other so when rewind button is pressed in between which means to start from the beginning and whih also means to display the launching image or mainviewcontroller whatever you say before loadingviewcontrollers

Comment: I see. I still hold that it is a memory management error though. EXC_BAD_ACCESS is an error that comes about when a message is sent to memorr, but the memory has no class to execute it. This means that it has either not been initialized yet, or has been released already. My best guess from what I can see of your code is that you appear to release viewController, when you still need it later. However, EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors can be hard to debug just by looking at code, so I really do suggest using NSZombies as a debugger tool.

Comment: i don't know if nszombie can be enabled for iPhone device too

Comment: Do you not have access to the simulator/Xcode debugging tools? Or is this error only happening on an actual iphone device and not on the simulator? NSZombie goes hand in hand with xcode, so if you can edit the code, you should be able to use NSZombie to debug it.

Comment: i enabled zombie objects in the diagnostics and tried to run but it doesn't tells me anything.

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry, the best advice I can give you then is to put in a bunch of NSLog statements throughout your code, and see exactly where/when you are getting the error.